# feynmf vs. feynmp: What's the difference?

Tags: packages, diagrams, feynmf

What is the difference between feynmf and feynmp?  By very basic understanding is that the former somehow makes use of raster graphics whereas the latter makes use of MetaPost.

Moreover, I have read that feynmp is actually preferable to feynmf, but why?  Is there something that you can do with feynmp that you cannot with feynmf?  Are some things easier?  Does it do the same things better?  I noticed very little difference when I changed `\usepackage{feynmf}` to `\usepackage{feynmp}`.  Indeed, the biggest difference was that I had to add an extra line of code in order for it to typeset without error!

Comment: And there is feynmp-auto,  which runs metapost on its own, so you do not have to worry about it.

Comment: In addition, `feynmp` supports color, `feynmf` doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`feynmf` uses METAFONT which will produce bitmaps. `feynmp`, on the other hand, uses METAPOST which will produce vectors.

Vectors are scalable - they scale smoothly without significant loss of quality. Bitmaps do not. This is the difference between an image in PNG or JPG format, on the one hand, and SVG or PDF format, on the other. The latter formats scale properly whereas the former do not. (Though PNG and JPG can be high-quality images, of course. But they need to be viewed at more-or-less the intended size else they will look pixellated.)

Moreover, METAFONT fonts display poorly in some PDF viwers. I'm not certain whether or not this applies to diagrams or only fonts, but if it applies to diagrams as well, you definitely do not want to use `feynmf` if your documents may be viewed with such software. Since the most notable viewers falling in the 'some PDF viewers' category are Adobe applications, this pretty much means you want to avoid METAFONT if sharing your documents with anybody you cannot be sure will use an alternative viewer.

In addition, MaxNoe pointed out that `feynmp-auto` enables you to automate the use of `feynmp`, and giordano added that `feynmp` supports colour, whereas `feynmf` will complain if colour options are used.